# Azure application automatic scale up

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, scale

I have an ASP.net app running on Azure app service. When the requests go above 1K, the whole site slows down and scaling up from S1 to S2(more RAM,CPU and ACU) resolves the issue.

How can I auto scale-up the service in certain hours like between 17:00 to 21:00 on weekends?

Is there any service in Azure for auto scaling up? I found auto scale-out in Azure but I want to do auto scale up.

Comment: Upgrade to a tier it feat your needs. You should autoscale out based on CPU rules to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no built-in Azure WebApp feature to make Azure WebApp scale up.

You can create Azure Function with time trigger or Azure Automation Account that will run in certain hours.
Then write C# or Powershell code that will make Azure WebApp scale up.